# Add Custom Columns to Object Explorer Details for Views in SQL Server 2008 Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I am using "Object Explorer Details", and when I am on "Tables", I can select many columns, particularly "Create Date".

However, when I am on "Views" or most any other part of the database, I only have a choice of columns "Name" and "Policy Health State".  I really want to also have the "Create Date" (like I used to have in SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager).

I know that right-clicking on an individual view and choosing "Properties" will give me the create date for that particular view.  But I want to see all the create dates for all the views and be able to sort on that column.

Is it in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Studio?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
use dbName
select name, create_date from sys.views
```

That'll give you all the information you're looking for.

Comment: So you have the same problem?  There is no way to get the info from "Object Explorer Details"?  It looks like tables and databases have mucho columns to configure, but everything else has only "Name" and "Policy Health State".

Comment: While the sys.views does give me the information, I cannot select the views and right-click and do any scripting.  Right-click scripting is only available in Object Explorer Details.